# Take photo after autofocusing automatically AVCapture

Tags: ios, swift4

I want to do this: When the camera is focused, the app will take picture automatically. But I found there's no way to detect if the camera is focused.
i'm using  AVFoundation for taking the picture
i'm new to iOS don't know how to code it
can anyone help me for this issue

Comment: Check the focus mode in AVCapture ios documentation -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1389191-focusmode

Comment: hi #Charan i didn't get how to do it , can you please share a sample code of it

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var error: NSError?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter{ $0.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) && $0.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back }
        if let captureDevice = devices.first as? AVCaptureDevice  {

            captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error))
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
            captureSession.startRunning()
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }
            if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
                previewLayer.bounds = view.bounds
                previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
                previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))
                cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"saveToCamera:"))
//get instance of phone camera
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
     //try to enable auto focus
     if(captureDevice!.isFocusModeSupported(.continuousAutoFocus)) {
         try! captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration()
         captureDevice!.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
         captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
        view.addSubview(cameraPreview)

     }
  }
        }
    }
    func saveToCamera(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData), nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: where i have to call the call this  photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)

Comment: That is for capturing the photo and i code which i gave you is just for continuous focussing

Comment: i just want to take a photo automatically  when the camera auto focus a object(eg a credit card)

Comment: when is focus is done, just call the capture photo function

Comment: how to know the focus is done and where i have to call the capture photo function

Comment: All those exclamation points make my eyes burn. Please read up on optionals and how to prevent crashes!

Comment: #charan its showing runtime error and not able to do this in swift4